# How to add some new variables to Gmap3 marker and retrieve them when a mouse event fire?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I'm having an issue with gmap3. I want to add some information to the marker and show them into the info window. But i don't know how to add these information to the marker because the default marker only contain some variable like: "title", "data" and some options.

And now i want to add some information such as address. How do i store them to the marker and get them when e mouse event fire?

```
 $('#gmap').gmap3({
        map:{
            options:{
                center:[10.823099,106.629664],
                zoom: 15
            }
        },
        marker:{
            values:Markers,
            options:{
                draggable: false
            },
            events:{
                click: function(marker,event,context){

                },
                mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
                    var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});

                    if (infowindow){
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        infowindow.setContent('<div class="infoWindow">'+context.data+'</div>');
                    } else {
                        $(this).gmap3({
                            infowindow:{
                                anchor:marker,
                                options:{content: context.data}
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                mouseout: function(){
                    var infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
                    if (infowindow){
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Here is my initialize function.

And this is my Markers:

```
marker = {
            latLng : [location.Latitude, location.Longitude],
            data   : '<span class="title"><b>'+location.Title+'</b></span>'+'<br>'+'<span class="address">'+location.Address+'</span>',
            options:{icon: 'data:image/png;base64,'+location.LocationType.Image},
            locationData: location
        };
        Markers.push(marker);
```

So the main question is: How do i retrieve locationData when click event fire?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself.

First go to the gmap3.js and edit the function:

```
function tuple(args, value) {
    var k, i,
        keys = ["data", "tag", "id", "events",  "onces", "locationData"],
        td = {};
```

Note that i have add locationData to keys.

Then go to function attach event and edit like this

```
function attachEvents($container, args, sender, id, senders) {
    var td = args.td || {},
        context = {
            id: id,
            data: td.data,
            tag: td.tag,
            locationData: td.locationData
        };
```

This way you have to edit the origin js file. Looking for another solution to make it better. 
Thanks